# NumericTraits Zero and One

Tags: c++, itk

It is possible to use `itk::NumericTraits` to get 0 and 1 of some type. Thus we can see this kind of code in the wild:

```
const PixelType ZERO = itk::NumericTraits<PixelType>::Zero;
const PixelType ONE = itk::NumericTraits<PixelType>::One;
```

This feels heavy and hard to read. As a programmer, I would prefer a more pragmatic version like:

```
const PixelType ZERO = 0;
const PixelType ONE = 1;
```

But is it entirely equivalent? I think the cast is done during the compilation so both versions should be identical in term of speed. If it's the case, why would anyone want to use `itk::NumericTraits` to get 0 and 1? There must be an advantage I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traits are typically used/useful in the context of generic programming. It's kind of heavily used in STL.

Lets consider your `NumericTraits` looks like below:

```
template <typename PixelT>
struct NumericTraits {
  static const int  ZERO = 0;
  static const int  ONE = 1;
};
```

In addition to this, you should or can constrain you template instance to a particular kind of type too..using enable_if et al.

Now, there comes a particular type of pixel which is special, how would you define `ZERO` and `ONE` for that ? Just specialize your `NumericTraits`

```
template <>
struct NumericTraits<SpecialPixel>{
  static const int ZERO = 10;
  static const int ONE = 20;
};
```

Got the idea and the usefulness? Now, another benefit of this is for converting value to type and then using it for tag dispatching:

```
void func(int some_val, std::true_type) {....}
void func(int some_val, std::false_type) {.....}

And call it like:

func(42, typename std::conditional<NumericTraits<PixelType>::ONE == 1, std::true_type, std::false_type>::type());
```

Which overload to call is decided at compile time here, relieving you from doing `if - else` checks and there by *probably* improving performance :)